# How to define template directory in this widget code

Tags: php, widgets

How can I define the template directory (So I can reference and image in the 'images' folder) from within this php widget code?

```
// WIDGET CODE GOES HERE
query_posts('posts_per_page=1&post_type=testimonial&orderby=rand');
if (have_posts()) : 
echo "<div class=\"testimonial-widget group\">";
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_post_thumbnail('widget-test-thumb');
    echo "<p><span class=\"left\">\"</span>";
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
            // IMAGE WOULD GO HERE
    echo string_limit_words($excerpt,15);
    echo "<span class=\"right\">\"</span></p>";
    echo "<h2>".get_the_title()."</h2>";
endwhile;
echo "</div>";
endif; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_template_directory_uri()` and it will return the url up to the template directory then you can just append the `'/images/FILENAME.EXT'` to it to pull in the image.